# Delphi 3 ApplyUpdates

Tags: delphi

I need to read data that has been posted to a table before ApplyUpdates is called.  Using Delphi 3 and Guptas SQLBase database.  When the data is posted, the records are not visible in the table until ApplyUpdates is called.

Does anyone know where the cached records are stored?

Comment: Delphi 3 or Delphi 4, or both?

Comment: @Dennis Are you using TClientDataSet or TTable/TQuery with cached updates?

Comment: Delphi 3 or 4 makes very little difference :)

Comment: @Idsandon I'm just pointing out that Dennis appears somewhat confused. Wasn't D4 the one which introduced dynamic arrays? But it was an even number and so very buggy? Or did I get that the wrong way round? I still remember the joy of D1. Happy days!

Comment: Using Delphi 3 with TQuery from SQLDirect.  Not using Midas.

Comment: Dynamic arrays are irrilevant here. MIDAS was introduced in D3, BDE cached updates could date back to D1, but I am not sure if it was already surfaced in BDE components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the database table, that's exactly how ApplyUpdates is supposed to work. Are you using MIDAS or cached updates? In the former case data are stored in the in-memory cache of TClientDataset, and can be accessed on the client side using TClientDataset methods (i.e. reading UpdateStatus, or setting StatusFilter) or accessing directly the Delta property. If you're using BDE cached updates, changes are stored AFAIK in some local temporary tables the BDE creates. You can still use UpdateStatus or UpdateRecordType to check for changes to records. In both situations, you have no way to see changes outside the client until they are applied - until then they exist only in the client local cache.

Comment: ah ha!!!  We are not using Midas, so I would presume we are using BDE cached updates.  Any ideas where I might look for the temp tables?

Comment: Check the BDE session temp folder (implicit or explicit TSession settings). But I would not access them directly.